# Do something after static blocks and before the main(String[]) method is called

Tags: java, swing, initialization

I want to trigger a `start()` method before the `main(String[])` method is called and after every static blocks (`static{}`) are triggered so that important parts of Java (like AWT/Swing) are fully functional when the method is ran.

start() loads files and images, sets a `SecurityManager` and opens a popup telling the user if everything went right or not. Unfortunately an exception is thrown when I am calling `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(stuff)`. http://pastebin.com/FG3y0i9Z

Using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` does not work and throws the same exception.

I think that this happens because AWT or Swing did not load itself properly through static blocks.

I do not have any control on the main method : I cannot modify it and I do not know its path.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Alternatively you could use premain method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html and attach agent

Comment: You probably wanting something else actually. Note that swing code is executed in separate thread, called "event dispatch thread". To put something into the queue of this thread you use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method.

Comment: @Dims An exception is thrown when I do that ( http://pastebin.com/FG3y0i9Z ) (I called start() in a static block)

Comment: @utybo, Could you elaborate on this question a bit. 1) In what sense don't you have control on the main method? 2) What are you trying to achieve by calling start?

Comment: @aioobe Just modified the question, please tell me if there is anything missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't about static blocks and stuff that did not load themselves; I had a problem because my SecurityManager blocked *everything*... I changed how I handled permissions (whitelist ==> blacklist) and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `start` from LAST static block.

Comment: How do you know which `static` block is "last"?

Comment: Which one is lowest in the file

Comment: Since he does not have control of the `main`, I assume there may be more than one file. I doubt that he can do it without modifying his `main`, though.

Comment: We should know more details probably

Comment: Anyway, last `static` will execute last and before main, but only if and when class loads

Comment: And there are other static blocks in the Java API that load stuff such as AWT, Swing, ...